# What is the difference between arbitrary indexing set $\mathbb R^J$ and $\mathbb R^n$ where $n$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In case of topology, how we'll define finite product of $\mathbb R$, infinite product and arbitrary product?

Comment: Do you not have a book or lecture notes telling you exactly how it's defined?

Comment: I have Munkres topology book,but I am confused.

Comment: Do you know what they are *as sets*?

Comment: R^n=(Rx....xR) n times,R^w=(RxR....)infinite times,R^J?This is the topic(product space) in which my concepts are not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could think of $\mathbb R^n$ as functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $\mathbb R$; $\mathbb R^\omega$ as functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb R^J$ as functions from $J$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: What is the difference between R^n and R^J?@J.W.Tanner can you please elaborate R^J case?With examples,please.

Answer (score 0):

All powers (finite, infinite) $\Bbb R^I$ where $I$ is some index set, is just the set of functions $\{f\mid f : I \to \Bbb R \}$, and more generally if $X_i, i \in I$ is a collection of sets, $$\prod_{i \in I} X_i = \{f \mid f: I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \land \forall i \in I: f(i) \in X_i\}$$

The finite case $X \times Y$, which is normally treated as a special case, occurs when  $I=\{1,2\}$, $X_1 =X, X_2= Y$ say and the function $f$ that sends $1$ to $x \in X$ and $2$ to $y \in Y$ is identified with the pair $(x,y)$ etc. But we can view all products in this uniform way.

The topology (in all such cases) has as its canonical subbase all sets of the form  $(\pi_j)^{-1}[O], j \in I$ where $\pi_j : \prod_{i \in I} X_i \to X_i$ is given by $\pi_j(f) = f(j)$, the $j$-th *projection*, and where $O \subseteq X_j$ is any open subset. This is the *smallest* (by inclusion) topology on the product that makes all $\pi_j, j \in I$ continuous.

Comment: I got your explanation,but what is the use of defining R^J when we already have R^n?

Comment: It's the other way around, $\Bbb R^n$ can be seen as a special case of $\Bbb R^J$ for any $J$. The finite case is very different topologically as well. $\Bbb R^J$ has many uses in analysis, in a disguised form (weak star topologies). The finite case $\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ does not generalise easily in this form.

Comment: If I speak truth,I am still not got the meaning of R^J.Like, what is difference between R^n and R^J?

Comment: @gilendragillu They're set of functions where the domain is finite ($n$ elements) or domain is $J$ (any set).

Comment: You mean R^n is a set where n is finite ,R^J means any set?Can you give some example that shows the difference?@henno brandsma

Comment: @gilendragillu a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. A typical point of $\Bbb R^n$ is $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: R^n is clear.R^J still not...

Comment: @gilendragillu it’s just the set of all functions from $J$ to $\Bbb R$. What don’t you understand about that?

Comment: today I read the theory of indexing set thing,and this is what I inferred:let J be our indexing set s.t. J={a1,a2,- - -};J can be finite or infinite set. If J={1,2,- - -,n} then it is a finite set used to make R^n,J=countably infinite then used to make R^w,J can be any arbitrary set.e.g. if J={4,5,6} can make R4xR5xR6 by mapping.Am I correct?

Comment: @gilendragillu If $J=\{4,5,6\}$ we consider functions with domain $\{4,5,6\}$ which are determined exactly by the triple $(f(4),f(5),f(6))$ so then $\Bbb R^J$ is essentially $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: yeah! Actually,in my mind it was a general set X.For me R4 was not R^4,was just an index.Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can you please help me in complex analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some common notations used in set theory:

- If $A$ and $B$ are two sets, $A^B$ denotes the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$,
- $0=\varnothing$ and the succesor of $n$ is $n \cup \{n\}$, so, for example, $1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0,1\}, 3 = \{0,1,2\}, \dots$
- $\omega$ denotes the set of all natural numbers: $\omega = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

With this,

- $\mathbb R^J$ is the set of all functions $J \to \mathbb R$,
- $\mathbb R^0 = \{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq1$ is the set of all functions $\{0,\dots,n-1\} \to \mathbb R$, which can be viewed as $n$-tuples like this: if $x \in \mathbb R^n$, write $x = (x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$, where $x_i := x(i)$.
- $\mathbb R^\omega$ is the set of all functions $\omega \to \mathbb R$, that is, the set of all real sequences: if $x \in \mathbb R^\omega$, write $x = (x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$, where $x_n := x(n)$.